# Gondolo-Gelmini Change of Variables

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, differentiation, integration, dark-matter

In the article *Cosmic abundances of stable particles: Improved analysis, P. Gondolo and G. Gelmini, Nucl. Phys. B 360 (1991), p. 145-179*, they convert $\rm{d}^3p_1\rm{d}^3p_2=2\pi^2p_1p_2\rm{d}E_1\rm{d}E_2\rm{d}\cos{\theta}$ (eq.3.2) into  $\rm{d}^3p_1\rm{d}^3p_2=2\pi E_1E_2\rm{d}E_+\rm{d}E_-\rm{d}s$ (eq. 3.4) with the following change of variables:

$$E_+=E_1+E_2, \quad E_-=E_1-E_2, \quad s=2m^2+2E_1E_2-2p_1p_2\cos{\theta}, \quad \rm{(eq. 3.3)}$$

When I try to derive the second expresion of $\rm{d}^3p_1\rm{d}^3p_2$ using these new variables $E_+,\ E_-, s$, I always get second order diferentials that in theory should vanish. I don't know how one could get $\rm{d}^3p_1\rm{d}^3p_2=2\pi E_1E_2\rm{d}E_+\rm{d}E_-\rm{d}s$.

They also define new limits of integration due to this change of variables: $\{ E_1>m,\ E_2>m, \ |\cos{\theta}|\leq 1 \}$ changes to $\{ s\geq 4m^2,\ E_+\geq \sqrt{s}, \ |E_-|\leq\sqrt{1-4m^2/s}\sqrt{E_+^2-s} \}$ (eq. 3.5). I get the first two, but I don't know how to compute $E_-$. The limit cases give some idea on how the expresion should be, but this is not enough to know the exact expresion, something like:
$$\rm{If} \quad E_+^2=s \implies E_-=0$$
$$\rm{If} \quad s=4m^2 \implies E_-=0$$
$$\rm{Then (?):} \quad |E_-| \leq \sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}\sqrt{E_+^2-s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume some general $A \bar{A}$ states where $\theta = \theta_{A \bar{A}}$.

The bound on $E_-$ is given by $|\cos \theta_{A\bar{A}}| \leq 1$ :

\begin{aligned}
\cos \theta_{A \bar{A}} = & \frac{2m_A^2 + 2E_{A}E_{\bar{A}} - s}{2 |\vec{p}_A| |\vec{p}_{\bar{A}}|} \\
= & \frac{4m_A^2 + E_+^2 - E_-^2 - 2s}{4 |\vec{p}_A| |\vec{p}_{\bar{A}}|} \\
= & \frac{4m_A^2 + E_+^2 - E_-^2 - 2s}{4\sqrt{(E_A^2 - m_A^2)(E_{\bar{A}}^2 - m_A^2)}} \\
= & \frac{4m_A^2 + E_+^2 - E_-^2 - 2s}{4\sqrt{E_A^2 E_{\bar{A}}^2 - m_A^2(E_A^2 + E_{\bar{A}}^2) + m_A^4}} \\
= & \frac{4m_A^2 + E_+^2 - E_-^2 - 2s}{4\sqrt{\left(\frac{E_+^2 - E_-^2}{4} \right)^2 - m_A^2 \frac{E_+^2 + E_-^2}{2} + m_A^4}} \\
= & \frac{4m_A^2 + E_+^2 - E_-^2 - 2s}{\sqrt{(E_+^2 - E_-^2)^2 - 8m_A^2 (E_+^2 + E_-^2) + 16m_A^4}}
\end{aligned}

Using Mathematica's Reduce function we get
\begin{equation}
E_-^2 \leq \frac{1}{s} (E_+^2 - s) (s - 4m_{A}^2)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered and I figured it out some time ago, I'll respond to my own post. You have to use the Jacobian to change variables:

$$    J_{ij}=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial E_+} & \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial E_+} & \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial s}\\
    \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial E_+} & \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial E_-} & \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial s}\\
    \frac{\partial \cos{\theta}}{\partial E_+} & \frac{\partial \cos{\theta}}{\partial E_-} & \frac{\partial \cos{\theta}}{\partial s}
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2E_2\\
    1 & -1 & 2E_1\\
    0 & 0 & -2 p_1 p_2
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$
Knowing that the determinant of the inverse matrix is the inverse of the determinant of the original matrix, we get $\det{J}=(4p_1 p_2)^{-1}$.
$$
    \mathrm{d}^3p_1 \mathrm{d}^3p_2 = \left(4\pi p_1 \mathrm{d}E_1\right) \left(4\pi p_2 \mathrm{d}E_2\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}\cos{\theta}\right) = 8\pi^2 p_1 p_2 \frac{1}{4p_1 p_2}\mathrm{d}E_+ \mathrm{d}E_- \mathrm{d}s = 2\pi^2\mathrm{d}E_+ \mathrm{d}E_- \mathrm{d}s.
$$
I guess the integrating limits logic is good enough. If anybody has something else to add there, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure! But I doubt there is some mistake in eq. 3.2

In the paper, it is mentioned that $$ d^3p_1d^3p_2=4\pi p_1dE_1 4\pi p_2 dE_2 \frac{1}{2}dcos\theta $$
and the author is using relativistic relations between energy and momentum.

So, $$ d^3p=4\pi p^2dp  $$
$$ p^2=E^2-m^2 $$
$$ 2pdp=2EdE $$
$$ pdp= EdE $$
Replacing this in the volume element
$$ d^3p=4\pi pEdE  $$
Now, eq. 3.2 becomes $$ d^3p_1d^3p_2=4\pi p_1 E_1dE_1 4\pi p_2 E_2 dE_2 \frac{1}{2}dcos\theta $$
And if we follow [Adri's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647645/263539) we can get eq. 3.4
$$ d^3p_1d^3p_2=2 \pi^2 E_1 E_2 dE_{+}dE_{-}ds $$